# How do I delete shortcuts in the rolling list of programs?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

1. What's the official term for this list?
2. Please see the question's title. How do I delete the shortcuts indicated beneath in red?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's the official term for this list?

It is simply known as the All Apps list (as its Start Menu title suggests).

> How do I delete the shortcuts [from this menu] indicated beneath in red?

There are essentially three types of applications in Windows 10:

#### 1. Desktop Applications (normal software)

Similar to previous versions of Windows,  you can simply remove the proper shortcuts in the appropriate folder. For Windows 10, this is currently either

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Or

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
```

Note that `%appdata%` above refers to *C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming*, with *Username* being an appropriate user on the system.

#### 2. Universal Apps (downloaded from the Microsoft Store) and 3. built-in "packages" (which are essentially pre-installed Universal Apps).

The only option is to uninstall them completely (they have no traditional shortcuts to remove).

This is straight-forward with traditional Universal Apps (those you install) but built-in packages need to be removed via the command line with [Windows PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) .

For a more complete overview, you may wish to look at this [How-To Geek article](https://www.howtogeek.com/224798/how-to-uninstall-windows-10s-built-in-apps-and-how-to-reinstall-them/). In short, however, the steps are:

- Press Windows+X, then select the “Windows PowerShell (Admin)” option.
- Use the command `Get-AppxPackage *package-name* | Remove-AppxPackage`.

The linked article has a relatively comprehensive list of these commands with specific package names. For those without the Spring 2017 Creators Update, the article notes:

> If you haven’t installed the Windows 10 Creators Update from Spring, 2017 yet, you might see the Command Prompt featured on the Power User menu instead of PowerShell. In this case, hit Start, type “PowerShell” into the search box, right-click the PowerShell result, and then select the “Run as administrator” option.

*Caveats*

As detailed in the article, a handful of packages cannot be uninstalled. Likewise, your relief from clutter may be short-term if an update decides to reinstall these items.